# Extract 10 digit number from a string (alpha numeric value)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

`Asfsdfdsfd 1234567890`

From the above example, how to extract only the 10-digit number in snowflake.
condition: If the length of the digits is more or less than 10, it should not extract that.

ex: `Asfsdfdsfd 1234567890123` here the length of the number is more than 10 then it should not extract the digits from the above scenario.

`select regexp_substr('asfsdfdsfd 123456789001', '[0-9]{10}') as extracted_digits where extracted_digits REGEXP '[0-9]{10}';`

Comment: Are the ten digits always supposed to be at the end of your input value?

Comment: What if you have multiple 10-digit numbers? And if the 10-digit number doesn't exist, do you want to return NULL, or the original string.?

Answer (score 0):

```
with table_cte as (
    select 'Asfsdfdsfd 1234567890' as vl 
    union 
    select 'Asfsdfdsfd 1234567890123' as vl
    
)
select 
    vl,
    regexp_substr(vl, '[ \w]([0-9]{10})$', 1, 1, 'e', 1) as extracted_digits
from table_cte;
```

This works assuming (based on your examples) that:

1. the number is proceeded by a space or a letter ([ \w])
2. it is on the end of string ($)

Check the documentation for reference: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr